# Google Sheets - DATE format not working on imported Date in TEXT format

Tags: date, google-sheets, format, google-sheets-formula

I text based .csv file with a semicolon separated data set which contains date values that look like this

```
22.07.2020
22.07.2020
17.07.2020
09.07.2020
30.06.2020
```

When I go to **Format>number>** I see the Google sheets has **automatic** set.
In this state I cannot use and formulas with this data.

I go to **Format>number>** and set this to **date** but formulas still do not see the actual date value and continue to display an error

[image: error message ot ouf google sheets]

Can someone share how I can quickly activate the values of this array so formulas will work against them?
I would be super thankful

Answer (score 1):

Where the date are in column A, starting in cell A1, this formula will convert to DATE as a number, after which you apply formatting to Short Date style.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,DATE(RIGHT(A1:A,4),MID(A1:A,4,2),LEFT(A1:A,2))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully(!) the dates stay as text, otherwise Google Sheets would sometimes detect MM/dd/yyyy instead of dd/MM/yyyy, and you won't be able to distinguish between July 9th and September 7th in your example.

### Solution #1

If your locale is for instance FR, you can then apply

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A="";;value(A1:A)))
```

[image]

### solution#2

you can try/adapt

```
function importCsvFromIdv1() {
  var id = 'the id of the csv file';
  var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  csvData.forEach(function(row){
    date = row[0]
    row[0] = date.substring(6,10)+'-'+date.substring(3,5)+'-'+date.substring(0,2)
  })
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  f.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me

Comment: what is your locale?

Comment: try the solution #2 by script

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to those that suggested a fix. I am not really a programmer and get cold sweats when I see suggesting of running scripts to solve simple problems. Sorry guys.

So the (non programmer) solution with the dates was to do a find/replace (CTRL + H) and replace all the (.)dots with (/)slashes, then to make sure the column is formatted as a date, then Google finally understands it as a date.

With the accounting values as well, I had to do the same find/replace to remove all the ' between thousands, then google woke up and understood them as numbers.

I am significantly underwhelmed by this from Google. They are getting too fat and lazy. They need some competition.